# How can I max/min values from firebase collection, when the collection data is a prop? (firebase, vue3)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I have a vue component which gets the data from a firebase collection:

```
const items = ref([]);
onMounted(async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(firebaseFireStore, 'SomeCollection'));
  let element = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const item = {
      id: doc.id,
      chosen_num: doc.data().CHOSEN_NUM,
      email: doc.data().EMAIL
    };
    element.push(item);
  });
  items.value = element;
});

let random = Math.random() * 100
let comp1Var = '1'
let comp2Var = '2'
```

It also renders another component with v-if:

```
<div v-if="random <= 20">
  <Comp1 :items="items"  :comp1Var="comp1Var"/>
</div>
<div v-else-if="random > 20">
  <Comp2 :items="items" :comp2Var="comp2Var"/>
</div>
```

the two child components define their props:

```
let props = defineProps({
  items: {
    type: Object
  },
  comp1var: { //or comp2Var in second component
    type: String
  },
})
```

is it possible to get the max/min values for `chosen_num` in the child components `props.items`?

pseudocode `props.items.chosen_num.getMax()`

thanks for any help!